# WindowsForm C# Autoscale with Macbook Retina Display

Tags: c#, windows, forms, scale, retina

I'm programming a WindowsForm Application and i have a problem about size of form.
I Design a form (name MainMenu) with Size 16:10 - 1900,1200.
This is picture (design)

[Please click to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuQBH.png)

but when i started it didn't have size like design in Visual Studio.
when I was using AutoScale Mode : None
It was like this : 
[Please click to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpIin.png)

when I was using AutoScale Mode : Font
It was like this :

(I can't post more than 2 links ... so so sorry)
and I used all of AutoScale modes, but it didn't work.

I using an Macbook 15inch retina display.

Comment: Sigh, the never ending mysteries of DPI scaling.  Declare your app [to be dpiAware](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034) and you can ignore the fact that your code is not actually dpi-aware for a while longer.  Run it on another (cheap) machine to see it go wrong again.

Comment: don't have any solution for that???